# Let $T: \mathbb{R}^{3} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ be a Linear Transformation such that…

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

$T(1,5,5)=\begin{bmatrix}5&0\\8&26\end{bmatrix}$ 
$T(0,1,5)=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\5&25\end{bmatrix}$ 
$T(0,0,1)=\begin{bmatrix}5&5\\33&151\end{bmatrix}$ 
Find a matrix $A\in\operatorname{Im}T$ such that $\det(A)=-245$
What I tried to do: finding a general matrix for the image of $T$ (by using the $3$ given vectors and their images) , But I got a very complicated matrix, to the point that I didn't finish calculating it and came here to ask before. 
 I would like to know if there's a trick that I didn't pay attention to or if there's an easier way to solve this question. 
 Aprreciate any help.

Comment: Note that the two answers only depend on $\det(B)=-5$ being negative. Any $v$ with $\det(T(v))<0$ can be scaled to achieve $\det(T(\lambda v)) = \lambda^2\det(T(v)) = -245$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B:=T(0,1,5)=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\5&25\end{bmatrix}.$ Then $B \in Im(T)$ and $\det (B)=-5.$

Let $ \alpha \in \mathbb R$ and let $A:=\alpha B$. Then $A \in Im(T)$ and $\det(A)=-5 \alpha^2.$

Now choose $ \alpha $ such that $-5 \alpha^2= -245.$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\det\bigl(T(0,1,5)\bigr)=-5$, $\det\bigl((7T(0,1,5)\bigr)=-49\times5=-245$. So, take$$A=7T(0,1,5)=\begin{bmatrix}0&7\\35&175\end{bmatrix}.$$